# How to perform Lookups in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, lookup, azure-data-factory

I'm a SSIS Developer. I do lots of SQL stored procedure lookup concepts in SSIS. But when coming to Azure Data Factory I haven't any idea how to perform a lookup using a SQL stored procedure.

Could anyone please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance !
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) is more of an ELT tool rather than ETL, therefore direct lookups are not supported.  Instead, this type of operation, along with other transforms is *pushed down into the compute* you are actually using.  For example, if you are moving data to SQL Server, Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Data Warehouse, you would ensure all data is on the same server and use a [Stored Procedure task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-stored-proc-activity) to execute the lookups using T-SQL and joins.  If you are using Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) you would use the [U-SQL Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity) to run U-SQL or execute ADLA stored procedures, again doing lookups via joins or custom U-SQL code such as Combiner, Applier, Reducer.  In fact you can use any of the ADF compute options like SQL, HDInsight (including Hive, Pig, Map Reduce, Streaming and Spark script), Machiine Learning or custom .net activities.

So you need to think about things differently with ADF.  Have a look through this article to gain greater understanding of transforming data in ADF:

**Transform data in Azure Data Factory**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-data-transformation-activities

As an aside, I would rarely use Lookups in SSIS as performance in early versions used to be poor.  Although this has been improved in later versions, generally if you can do it in SQL you probably should.  This pattern harnesses the power of SQL Server, rather than dragging data up into the SSIS pipeline, eg for the purposes of lookups (which are essentially joins) and pushing the data back out again.  I reserve Data Flow transformations mainly when non-relational data is involved, eg xml or joining your email server with relational data.  This is my personal view anyway : )

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive explanation!
Basically, I do also file levels operations. Let’s to be say exactly 
Our input file has many fields (let’s say #50 in number) with, (comma) delimiter. We should modify/make the file to write an acceptable output file.
I have some question on the above related transformation like. Would you please clarify those for me?

Comment: 1. How do we do the simple string concatenation? -I go through the custom activity with .NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities). But not sure which part of function/codes will be used for my simple concatenation. Also, is there any other way than custom Activity to do this?

2. How to copy a file from a Clients SFTP server and move to my azure cloud storage? Is there is any built-in Task available or we should do this in same custom activities?

Comment: 3. How to rename/deletion a file from Clients SFTP?

4. How to do perform a simple operation e.g., if #field1 = "male" then our output file contains the column #field4 in the first row?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The answers depend on what compute you are using.  If the input and output files are both flat file then I would probably use U-SQL / ADLA to do this rather than custom task.  You could also choose to import the data into an Azure SQL DB where your lookup tables also exist and do the lookups there as joins.  Make sense?  Perhaps give a bit more info about what you're doing and the output file.

Comment: Yes Bob the input and output files are both flat files also i use some lookup (as joins) using Azure SQL DB.                                                                                 To be more clear i attached the input and output files in the below link Input File [link]https://gist.github.com/jayendranarumugam/c3de8f175b36ebd87739f7403f25775a                                                                             
Output File [link]https://gist.github.com/jayendranarumugam/c3de8f175b36ebd87739f7403f25775a

Comment: So how you would do this in Data Factory is use a Copy Activity to load the data from flat file into a db table, then call a Stored Proc task to do all the hard work in the db ie the compute), including lookups, string concat etc then another Copy activity to export the data to flat file.

Comment: Updated my comment above Bob !

Comment: As you said if we are using copying activity then such a large amount of data's(input file) have to copy/write into DB then finally exporting those large amount data's (output file) from  DB to flat-file is going to Costlier ?

Also if we are using DB for storing/writing  for every file.It would be also cause maintenance issue.?It will keep increasing the size of the DB as well !

Comment: You could always clean up the db after you are finished?  Or U-SQL/ADLA might be a better option then?  Try each one out and cost it up as a proof-of-concept.  Even if you use custom activity it is still going to cost you because the point is you need some compute to do the work.

Comment: Clean up in the sense we are going to delete/drop the DB/Table after we complete our Works ?                                                                                   If we use U-SQL/ADLA then the same will follow as Copy Activity ? Like Copying activity to load the data's into ADLA then using U-SQL queries to pull up the data's we want all the transformation in Store proc task then export in to another flat file ?

Comment: Simply truncate the table.  ADF has recently added support for SFTP, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-sftp-connector).  Stored Proc task is for SQL only.  Use U-SQL task to run U-SQL.

Comment: Is this answer still the case in version2 of Data Factory? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity

Comment: Hi @Jim, ADFv2 (currently in preview) now supports running SSIS packages as part of an [Integration Runtime (IR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime).  It also supports a [Lookup Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) but there is no other in-built transform.  So IMHO ADFv2 is still inherently an ELT tool, but one that can host ETL packages, if that makes sense.