# Is there something in Azure Data Factory akin to FOR/FOREACH loops in SSIS?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have data in 200+ tables in on-prem database which I need to move to Azure Data Lake. I am not happy about idea of having 200+ separate pipelines (or one pipeline with 200+ activities or some other partitioning of pipelines/activities of thereof)in Azure Data Factory one for each table. Are there better/more scalable ways to do this? in SSIS I would likely to create a template package and wrap it in a for-loop container to iterate through a list of tables to do the work or, to take it a step further, have a few lists and each package working on its own list independently for greater parallelism. Are there ways to do the same in data factory?

Answer (score 2):

Really?  SSIS is terrible as far as dynamic schema is concerned.  As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731569/how-to-perform-lookups-in-azure-data-factory/43733373?noredirect=1#comment74573324_43733373), Azure Data Factory (ADF) is an ELT tool not an ETL tool and is fundamentally different in that way.  However it wouldn't take that long to do this using the Copy Wizard.

Alternately, you will have to learn to use the .net SDK and/or Powershell with ADF to work with it more dynamically.  You would in theory need input and output datasets for each table which could run under one pipeline.

Lastly, I don't think this is a great pattern (mainly because you need some IaaS to host it) but as a last resort,  SSIS does now have integration with Azure Data Lake in the 2016 Feature Pack.

Comment: I am mostly alluding to the manageability aspect of the task. 200+ tables is way too much to manage under single project to have 200+ input/output datasets and pipelines connected with each other. SSIS feature pack is not that useful. I did try it...

Comment: @YuGagarin Run through the SSIS approach for me.  How do you propose that works with dynamic schema?  You could always use SSIS to output the files to a fileshare, then use ADF to pick up and move the files.  A Copy Activity could move all the files in the directory, only one pipeline, input dataset (source directory) and output dataset (output directory) required.  You could also try using a Stored Proc task, run through all the tables in the db, output the files to a fileshare, then Copy Activity etc. The point is ADF only orchestrates, the looping will happen on your chosen compute.